# Differences in AJAX syntax: $.ajax vs $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax

So Ive seen AJAX syntax done two different ways. Seems like on the boards here everyone uses the format like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'mm.php',
data: { color: color},
success: function (res) {

},
error: function (jqXHR) {

}
```

But my text uses

```
$.post('mm.php', data, processResponse);
```

Is there a difference and what is preffered?

Comment: [The latter is just a shorthand syntax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Visit http://api.jquery.com - enjoy. Personally, I *use deferred objects* for jQUery AJAX request event handling. I find it works better across single-purpose functions and allows composition via `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

[http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/]

Comment: Ah. I guess what I dont recognize is why there is a data AND a datatype

Comment: it depends on datatype of data (You have to omit it, if you dont know what kind data are you sending, but it is better to choose one - as a string), from original documentation:

The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: oh. So you would do something like dataType: text if you were expecting an array output from a PHP page?

Comment: dataType: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
Please, use quotes - it is a string:


"text": A plain text string.


**dataType: "text"**

Answer (score 1):

Would it help to understand with this form:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mm.php',
    data: { color: color},
    success: processResponse,
    error: function (jqXHR) {
    }
});
```

- basically the `.post` is a shorthand for the long version of `.ajax`

EDIT PER COMMENT:

```
var color = "red";
var mydata = {color: color};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mm.php',
    data: mydata,
    success: processResponse,
    error: function (jqXHR) {
    }
});
```